# Rendering video stream in webpage without VLC activex

Tags: flash, video-streaming, libvlc, ip-camera

I am building a software component for a VMS (Video Manager System) that is in short a video retransmition server. What its component allow is connect to a video source (ip-camera, screen, file,webcam), transcode this video and  stream video to multiple locations simultaneously. I am using VlcWrapper (C#) for connect to a source and transcoding. I have a web app (asp.net mvc) that is the frontend that let configure the output for transcoding, I need to view the original video and the transcoded video in the site at the same time for comparing. I try vlc activex but the control is not good for me. I know flash could be used for this but i don't known how to use it.

Comment: What exactly you don't like in Vlc ActiveX?

Comment: Because i don't need the toolbar button it has, the only thing i need is rendering the video like in a canvas.

Comment: Toolbar in Vlc ActiveX could be disabled. Or you could try http://webchimera.org/ - it has highly customizable UI. With WebChimera you could show both videos in the same window, and even do some transition effects if you will need it. Or you could use FBVLC compatibility mode, if you need only video and nothing else...

Comment: Forgot to mention - WebChimera plugin is open source and based on libvlc